# Notification from Web Notifications API Not Visible in Chrome

Tags: javascript, notifications

I'm attempting to display a notification using the Web Notifications API in Chrome version 122 running on localhost. The notification permission is granted, and `window.isSecureContext` returns `true`. Although the `show` event for the notification is triggered, indicating that the notification should be visible, it doesn't appear on the screen. This behavior is observed even when no browser or system-level "Do Not Disturb" modes are active, and there are no apparent errors in the console.

Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```js
Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
  if (permission === 'granted') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const notification = new Notification('Title', { body: 'Body' });
      notification.addEventListener('show', (event) => {
        console.log('Notification shown', event);
      });
      notification.addEventListener("close", function (event) {
        console.log('Notification closed');
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

I've checked the following:

- Notification settings in Chrome for localhost are set to allow notifications.
- The system's notification center does not contain the missed notification.
- Testing in an Incognito window to rule out extensions affecting behavior.
- Notification in Edge is also not visible.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can offer insight into why the notification might not be displaying as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's unlikely that you have the same case, but I was having the same problem with Chrome 122 on MacOS (10.15.7). My problem was that for some reason and by default, Google Chrome notifications were disabled from the notification center in system preferences.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've checked on Windows 10 and it works. Thanks)